# SP 2010 Distribution Lists with Incoming Email not working across One-Way domain trust

Tags: incoming-email

Here is my setup.  Domain A has a one-way forest trust with domain B such that Domain B users can access resources on Domain A's network but Domain A users cannot access resources on Domain B.

My SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise is setup on Domain A with the service account being in Domain B.

I have incoming email configured and working for SharePoint.  When I email enable a sharepoint group, it creates the DL and any Domain A users I add to that group get correctly added to the DL in AD.  But when I try to add a Domain B user to that group, they never show up in the DL and there is an error in my ULS log:

System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while translating user name 'DomainB\Userid' to a Windows account name. (DS_NAME_ERROR_DOMAIN_ONLY)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.EmailIntegration.SPEWSUtil.TranslateUserName(String name, DS_NAME_FORMAT formatOffered, DS_NAME_FORMAT formatDesired)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.EmailIntegration.SPEWSADManager.AddUsersAsMembers(DirectoryEntry distGroupEntry, String Alias, String[] MembersNt4NameList)SPEWSADManager::AddUsersAsMembers Unable to translate user name domainB\userid to FQDN name.

It seems that when SP created the DL, it created it as a universal group.  I changed it to domain local and can add users to the DL from Domain B but even after this change, SP still generates the error above.

Has anyone gotten this working in a multiple forest/domain scenerio before or have any thoughts on next steps to troubleshoot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a case with Microsoft and they pointed me to this KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=979565

The article is for SP 2007 but it sounds like the issue still exists for SP 2010.